# Wrong data over users google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am building one BI over analytics data. Users Tracking give different numbers over different dimensions (Hour, Day, Week, Month) in the same period of dates.

How do I explain this? Is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Users is not a metric that you can sum for different time ranges as one user can have sessions in multiple time ranges and so simply summing the number of users each day won't equal the total number of users in a week etc.